# Binomial math symbol like but with square braces

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I want to generate symbol like this:

[image]

But I can't find a proper method in LyX. I tried frame decoration with `\overset` like this:

[image]

I also tried square braces with matrix inside, but is too large.
It's surprising that LyX doesn't offer equal size room inside "frame decorations". How can I do here?

Comment: I use `{a \brack b}` for this.

Answer (score 3):

The construction you want to place is referred to under AMS math as a "small matrix". Here are the steps:

1. Insert > Math > Inline Formula
2. Insert > Math > Delimeters or click on the [image] button and select the delimiters `[` (for left) and `]` (for right):

   [image]
3. Within the inline formula type `\smallmatrix` and hit <kbd>→</kbd>. This inserts a `smallmatrix` environment inside the delimiters.
4. Now you insert elements in the same way you do a regular array or tabular; for example, insert `x`, then a new line (by pressing the [image] button), moving over to the second element (by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> button), insert `y`.

   [image]
5. Compile to view the output:

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Try inserting the following TeX code.

```
\bigl[\!\begin{smallmatrix} a \\ b \end{smallmatrix}\!\bigr]
```

If that doesn't look right (it might be slightly too tall), you could also try

```
\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a \\ b \end{smallmatrix}\right]
```

or

```
\left[\!\begin{smallmatrix} a \\ b \end{smallmatrix}\!\right]
```

and see if they look nicer to you.